# Problem with Installing intel-linux-graphics-installer in 13.10 : Dependency problems

Tags: 13.10, intel-graphics

When I try in `apt-get install` intel drivers I have this errors:

[image]

I don't know what I do wrong.

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `intel-linux-graphics-installer` doesn't have a saucy (13.10) version.
you will have to wait until a new version is out.

Reference :
[Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.2 for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux)

[Support ubuntu 13.10 | Linux Graphics](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/237)